# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'idDepartment' at row 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, bootstrap-4

Before downvoting this question, please understand my frustration. I have been at this issue for the past 4 hours. I am working on small application for a project for uni and this error has almost caused to quit completly. My application has an `Edit` button in which the user can choose which `row` from my `mysql` database to edit. Once they choose it asks them to fill out the `First name, Last Name, DepartmentId, and Specialty`. After that if successful it will display the new `field` onto the page. I believe the issue is that my `idDepartment` is a `int` and the `form` is passing it in as a `string`. I have tried converting it using 
`$idDepart = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $idDepart);` But this does not work for me. Can someone please help. I must complete this by tonight. I will post both of my `php` files down below.

Update: [image]

`index.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php require_once 'formprocessor.php';?>
  <!-- Based on query type it will use bootstrap alert class -->
  <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
    <div class = "alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type'] ?>">

    <?php
        // Based on the message type it will echo it and then unset the session
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
        ?>

    </div>
    <!-- End of if statment -->
    <?php endif ?>
  <div class = "container">

  <?php
    // Connect to databse 
    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', "", 'v2HospitalDB')
    or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    // Will select everthing from Doctor and display on the page
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Doctor") or die($mysqli->error);
    ?>


    <!-- This is the format for the table with the folowing columns -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th> Doctor ID </th>
                 <th> First Name </th>
                 <th> Last Name</th>
                 <th> Department ID</th>
                 <th> Speciality </th>
                 <th colspan="2"> Action </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php
    // everything is fetched from db and stored in row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>
        <!-- Each row will have its repsected column from the database -->
            <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $row['doctorID']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['doctorFName']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['doctorLname']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['idDepartment']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['specialty']; ?></td>


            <td>
                <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['doctorID']; ?>"
                    class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                <a href="formprocessor.php?delete=<?php echo $row['doctorID'];?>"
                     class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

            </td>
            </tr>

            <?php endwhile;
            ?>


        </table>

    </div>

    <?php

    // This function prints the array in a nice format
    function pre_r($array) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($array);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    ?>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form action="formprocessor.php" method="post">

    <!-- hidden input field for the update -->
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label> First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" placeholder="Enter First Name">
    </div>

    <div label="form-group">
    <label> Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" name="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
    </div>

    <div label="form-group">
    <label> Department ID</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $idDepart;?>" name="departmentID" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter DepartmentID">
    </div>

    <div label = "form-group">
    <label> Speciality </label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $special;?>" name="speciality" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Specialty">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <?php 
    if($update == true): ?>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`formprocessor.php`

```
<?phpsession_start;


// starting a session so we can go back to main page




// Connect to mysql database 
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root',"",'v2HospitalDB') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
// If we are not able to connect for some reason then this will run below
if (!$mysqli) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Error code from last connect call: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Error description from last connect error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
// Reset values to empty 
$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";
$departID = "";
$special =  "";
$update = false;
$id = 0;

// Check if the save button has been pressed
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    // store columns from database
    $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lname'];
    $departID = $_POST['departmentID'];
    $special =  $_POST['speciality'];



    // Insert records into database
    $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO Doctor(doctorFName , doctorLname , idDepartment, specialty)
     VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$departID' , '$special')") or
    die($mysqli->error);

    // will show at top of screen once the record has been saved
    $_SESSION['message'] = "You have saved a record into the database";
    $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";

    // redirect back to the index.php after inserting records
    header("location: index.php");
}

// This will delete the record from the table based on the id
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $id = $_GET['delete'];
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM Doctor WHERE idDepartment AND doctorID = '$id'") or die($mysqli->error);


 // When you delete a record, will show at top of screen
 $_SESSION['message'] = "You have saved a deleted a record from the database";
 $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
    // redirect back to the index page
    header("location:index.php");
    // session_destroy();




}

// If the edit button is clicked
if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
    $update = true;
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    // change back to where doctorId and idDepartment
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Doctor WHERE doctorID = '$id'") or die($mysqli->error);
    // will fetch all colums in table from the result array
    // If the record has been found in the database
    if(count($result) == 1){
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        $firstname = $row['doctorFName'];
        $lastname = $row['doctorLname'];
        $idDepart = $row['idDepartment'];
        $special = $row['specialty'];
        //  echo (var_dump($result));


    }

     // will show at top of page when user updates the table
     $_SESSION['message'] = "Record has been selected";
     $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "info";
    //  header('location: index.php');
    //  session_destroy();

}

// If user clicks update then will insert values into columns
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $firstname = $_POST['doctorFName'];
    $lastname = $_POST['doctorLname'];
    $idDepart = $_POST['idDepartment'];
    $special = $_POST['specialty'];

    $idDepart = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $idDepart);


    $mysqli->query("UPDATE Doctor SET doctorFName = '$firstname', 
    doctorLname = '$lastname', idDepartment = '$idDepart', 
    specialty = '$special' WHERE doctorID = $id ") or die($mysqli->error);

//   $mysqli->query(" INSERT INTO Doctor (doctorID,doctorFName,doctorLname, 
//   idDepartment,specialty) VALUES( null , '$firstname','$lastname',
//   '$idDepart','$special') ") or die($mysqli->error);


    // will show at top of page when user updates the table
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Record has been updated";
    $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "warning";
    header('location: index.php');
    // session_destroy();

}
```

Comment: You have `$idDepart = $_POST['idDepartment'];`, but your input is -> `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $idDepart;?>" name="departmentID"...`

Comment: Exasperating doesn't help get questions answered. Avoid [SQL injection too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: so should I change it to this `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $idDepartment; ?>">` in my  `index.php`
@Sean

Comment: can you please explain your answer @Sean.

Comment: What @Sean was saying is that your input will be in `$_POST['departmentID']`, not `$_POST['idDepartment']`

Comment: Okay after changing to what @Nick said, I am now not able to see the `firstname,lastname, and specialty` anymore. I will pos a picture above

Comment: `if(count($result) == 1){` should be `if ($result->num_rows == 1)`

Comment: THANK YOU @Sean you have saved me so much time. You don't understand how happy I am!!!

Comment: Thank you also @Nick. You are an amazing person!

Comment: Also, avoid using single quotes for `PHP` variables that holds integers values when you made the query string. Example: `UPDATE Doctor SET doctorFName = '$firstname', doctorLname = '$lastname', idDepartment = '$idDepart', specialty = '$special' WHERE doctorID = $id` should be replaced by this: `UPDATE Doctor SET doctorFName = '$firstname', doctorLname = '$lastname', idDepartment = $idDepart, specialty = '$special' WHERE doctorID = $id` if the variable `$idDepart` holds an integer. This way, you will avoid the engine to autocast (if enabled) to the correct type.